# Validation rule to restrict user from changing opportunity owner

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule, record-owner

I need to restrict one specific user from changing the owner on an opportunity.

Their ID is : 0056T000008AUlqQAG and they are a Sys Admin.

I found this on salesforce : `$User.Id  <>  "userID" &&  ISCHANGED(OwnerId)`

I tried changing it to `$User.Id  =  "0056T000008AUlqQAG" &&  ISCHANGED(OwnerId)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the user id 18 digit. Can you give the user id as 15 digit and check it should work. The validation rule should be as below.

```
$User.Id  =  "0056T000008AUlq" &&  ISCHANGED(OwnerId)
```

Please find the [below](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdWwXUAV/allow-18-character-ids-in-validation-rules) idea for the same. Instead of that you can try using the name of the user as it is always not a good practice to hardcode the ids